# How would one automate this?

Tags: actionscript-3, automation, numbers, integer, visible

Okay, so I know this is a really stupid question but I've been working on this for so long that my brain has gone to mush. How would I automate the following (this is just an example)

```
if(numberofmachines == 1) {
        machines.machine1.visible = true;
    }

    if(numberofmachines == 2) {
    machines.machine1.visible = true;
    machines.machine2.visible = true;
    }

    if(numberofmachines == 3) {
    machines.machine1.visible = true;
    machines.machine2.visible = true;
    machines.machine3.visible = true;
    }
```

Basically I had an i integer setup between 1 and 3 and I tried:

```
if(numberofmachines == i) {
        machines["machine" + i].visible = true
    }
```

I had taught about doing `>=i.visible = true`, etc. but obviously I'm too stupid to get it :/ Any help or could someone guide me in the right direction? Really appreciate it

Comment: A very simple `for` loop can do the job : `for(var i:int = 1; i <= numberofmachines; i++){ machines["machine" + i].visible = true; }` ...

Comment: @akmozo Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, what exactly you are trying to achieve. But I would probably go with some loop cycle like:

```
for(var i = 1; i<=3;i++){
  machines["machine" + i].visible = numberOfMachines <= i;
}
```